# Watson Machine Learning (SPSS) with IBM Data Science Experience (DSX)

Tags: data-science-experience

I've written a stream file and demonstrated to my colleagues. It is not working now. It displays stream error. Also says "Due to domain migration, we need to reconfigure your project storage to restore load capability". Does this message contributing the error?

I've re-written once again. If I run the Analysis node, it doesn't give results by 1_Training and 2_Testing. It gives results for the whole data set.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the project owner to visit the project and trigger the reconfiguration. It should be a simple click of a button. If that doesn't work, contact IBM support through the chat box at the bottom right of the screen.

Or else create your own project and test your notebook there.

If you want anyone to look for problems in your code, you'll have to post it.